# Find text based on HTML Comment

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

How do I use Nokogiri to find text within `<!--Sanction 3-->` (Parsing the HTML)?

I am entering a search term into the site and the results are displayed on the next page. I need to programmatically grab the data from the results page if it meets certain criteria.

I noticed as I analyzed the results page, that the items are broken up into sanctions. I need to know if the sanction has data and, if so, does it contain my keyword; I am looking for the county/state. I am not sure how to make it look at a sanction. Here is a bit of the HTML:

```
<!--Sanction 3-->

<table border="2" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="XXheaderClass" colspan="5" scope="colgroup">
                <table bgcolor="#ff9999" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="XXsanctionHeader1">
                                <span class="XXtextBold">Requirements Met</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="XXsanctionHeader2">
                                <span class="XXtextBold">Status: GOOD</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="XXheaderClass" width="31%" scope="col">
                <span class="XXsmallTextBold">Description</span>
            </th>
            <th class="XXheaderClass" width="12%" scope="col">
                <span class="XXsmallTextBold">Effective Date</span>
            </th>
            <th class="XXheaderClass" width="12%" scope="col">
                <span class="XXsmallTextBold">Number</span>
            </th>
            <th class="XXheaderClass" width="12%" scope="col">
                <span class="XXsmallTextBold">County/State</span>
            </th>
            <th class="XXheaderClass" width="33%" scope="col">
                <span class="XXsmallTextBold">Address and Phone Number</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td class="footerClass" colspan="5">
                <table class="panelBox">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="SanctionHelpPages/Sanction03Help.aspx" id="MainContent_lvSanction3_sanction03Link" class="outputLinkEx"><span class="XXlinkBold">
                                    Click Here</span></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="XXtextBold">to resolve,
                                requirements met.</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>

        <tr id="MainContent_lvSanction3_Tr1_0">
            <td class="XXsmallText">
                <span id="MainContent_lvSanction3_lblDescription_0">DESCRIPTION     </span>
            </td>
            <td class="XXsmallText">
                <span id="MainContent_lvSanction3_lblEffectiveDate_0">9/19/20011</span>
            </td>
            <td class="XXsmallText">
                <span id="MainContent_lvSanction3_lblNumber_0">1111             </span>
            </td>
            <td class="XXsmallText">
                <span id="MainContent_lvSanction3_lblCountyState_0">MyCounty       </span>
            </td>
            <td class="XXsmallText">
                <span id="MainContent_lvSanction3_lblAddressAndPhoneNumber_0">1234 MyRoad AVE. CITY                                        (xxx)xxx-xxxx</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
```

Comment: So you are looking to extract data cells from the table *only within "sanction" 3* where the "CountyState" contains your search term? What data cells do you need to extract? What do the other "sanctions" contain?

Comment: @MarkThomas I need information from one other sanction also. The other sanction is laid out the same as above. Depending on the search the sanctions may or may not be there. There may be one or many "CountyState" depending on the search results.

Comment: How are we supposed to identify what information you want? Do you want *all* sanctions that contain a matching CountyState?

Comment: @MarkThomas Sorry, I thought if I could figure out one then I could figure out the other. I need the two sanctions in seperate conditional statements. For example, if sanction 3 has data and the countystate = x then put "line" into file "A" (and some sort of thing for the other sanction I need data from). I understand how to write my conditional statement I just don't know how it to point to just sanction 3. Right now my statements are looking at the entire page thus I am getting incorrect output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `doc.xpath("//comment()")` to find all of the comment nodes. You could then iterate through those nodes and check their siblings for your data. Without more information it's somewhat difficult to give a comprehensive answer, though.

Comment: +1 Agreed mostly. I'd ignore the comment nodes and look at the underlying table, searching for text inside there that identifies the desired content. As a last-resort I'd look for the comments. But that's just me.